# What is the effect of temperature on dry hopping?

Tags: temperature, dry-hop, dry-hopping

How does the temperature at which you do dry hopping effect the aroma of the beer? Is there any effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warmer the beer when you dry hop the faster the hop oils are drawn out of the hops providing aroma.  You can cut down the amount of days needed for dry hopping by doing it at room temp as opposed to refrigeration temps.

Vinnie Cilurzo from Russian River Brewer eludes to the benefits of warmer dry hopping temperatures in ["Brew a Double IPA"](http://www.homebrewersassociation.org/attachments/0000/6351/doubleIPA.pdf) published in the July/August 2009 issue of Zymurgy.

Comment: i've heard that, but can you quantify it in any way?

Comment: @baka  There aren't any measures of aroma and flavor available.  Mainly because its hugely subjective based on the individual.

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect that while temperature plays a role, it might not be as drastic as one thinks.  Many things in the world happen faster when heat is applied (or in this case when things are warmer).

But there is very little emperical evidence of someone dry hopping for 5 days at room temp vs 5 days at cellar temps and reported a noticable (or dissapointing difference).

If the beer is destined to get chilled anyway, why not just dry hop a little longer and get the chilling and subsequent clearing that comes with lower temps started sooner.